# Are variables inside VB.NET shared function local only?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

ASP.NET VB.NET 3.5.

In the following function, called from a webpage AJAX, will the cVSession2 object be shared with other users (I don't want it to be)?

```
 <WebMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function fGPSUpdateSessionValues(ByVal strLatitude As String, ByVal strLongitude As String) As String

        Dim strReturn As String = ""

        Dim cVSession2 As New cVSession
        With cVSession2
            .pVSessionGPSLatitudeLastPosition = strLatitude
            .pVSessionGPSLongitudeLastPosition = strLongitude
            .fUpdate()
        End With

        cVSession2 = Nothing

        Return strReturn

    End Function
```

Comment: What did you find when you tested it for yourself?

Comment: Why is it a function anyways when you return an empty string all the time? IMO rethink your approach.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was after a theoretical answer to bypass the risk that any test I used wasn't bulletproof. So far no noticeable sharing but the lifetime of the instantiation was so short that maybe only with thousands of calls would an issue arise if it were to.

Comment: @Zaggler we hadn't decided yet if we wanted a return string. That was there just in case.

Comment: That's not what SO is for.  It is for specific issues.  There are other sites that are for that type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears local variables such as cVSession2 will not be shared with other users as per:

[Does a static method share its local variables & what happens during concurrent usage from different threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473615/does-a-static-method-share-its-local-variables-what-happens-during-concurrent)